# Congruence, two numbers, what number to choose to get expected result

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Two people A and B pick a number, for example from 1 to 25, A doesn't know what B picked, and B doesn't know the number A picked. Then the two numbers are added and the sum is divided by 25. Is there any way B can choose a number so that the remainder is greater than 10?

This isn't a problem from any textbook. It's just something I've been thinking about, so the values given are irrelevant.

I would really appreciate any hints, ideas.

Comment: If $A$ uses uniform distribution, then what $B$ picks is irrelevant.

Comment: So there is absolutely no solution to that problem?

Comment: What do you mean by solution?

Comment: Not without some further restrictions...

Comment: @dtldarek By solution I meant a minimal number B has to give in order for the remainder to be at least x.

Comment: @DonAntonio What restrictions would we need?

Comment: Absolutely no solution. Perhaps if you remove the 'mod $25$' part, then A has to say at least $9$ in your original example.

Comment: Yes, that I know. Well, anyway. It's quite interesting that such a short and seemingly simple problem can have no solution ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$B$ cannot know beforehand what $A$ has chosen $a$ to be, so he cannot distinguish beforehand whether $a$ will be $1$, $10$, or $16$ (or any other number). In the first case, $B$ would want to choose a number $b$ greater than $9$. But if it's greater than $9$, $B$ would actually want it to be at least $20$ so that $b + 16 \pmod{25} > 10$. But then if it turns out that $a = 10$, then $B$ loses.

From a higher point of view, if $B$ chooses uniformly randomly, then any number between $0$ and $24$ are equally likely regardless of $A$'s choice. In this way, we have that there is no strategy for $B$.

Finally, you say that there is no solution, but I would argue that there is a solution, and the solution is exactly that $B$ has no winning strategy.